# Ajax response data getting severally

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

[This is my console.log result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qY07m.png) I need to get  response as severally.
Also I here is result based on image

```
{
    "download": "0.15698, 0.11142, 0.24579, 0.42217, 0.16009, 0.14763, 0.14108, 0.37508, 0.13011, 0.26782, 0.14398, 0.14989, 0.56165, 0.94662, 0.78994, 1.11108, 1.68576, 2.26573, 2.10515, 2.36522, 1.54842, 1.40649, 1.09299, 1.52076, 0.79385, 1.20544, 1.45247, ",
    "upload": "0.19302, 0.18774, 0.18749, 0.22306, 0.30178, 0.32726, 0.25402, 0.24653, 0.23101, 0.47355, 0.16979, 0.19405, 0.22266, 0.26537, 0.25092, 0.26198, 0.18231, 0.21553, 0.22306, 0.21779, 0.20615, 0.20732, 0.18985, 0.17835, 0.16846, 0.19416, 0.15295, 0.14216, 0.17618, 0.24072, 0.15099, 0.18762, 0.16171, 0.19065, 0.18126, 0.19872, 0.19990, 0.16208, 0.17508, 0.22508, 0.20447, 0.21504, 1.22086, 1.38581, 1.29675, 1.19692, 1.30740, 1.04923, 1.19475, 1.30771, 1.22749, 1.17226, 1.34684, 1.15108, "
}
```

```php
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    async: true,
    url : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "Graphs/get_graphs",
    dataType: 'json',
    data :{hotel_name_realm:$("#hotel_names").val()},
    success : function(res){
      console.log(res);
    }
});
```

I need to get download and upload separately inside success function.
Here is my console image

Comment: Why not just access them as `res.download` and `res.upload`?

Comment: i tried that way but it shows as undefined

Comment: whats the response of console ?

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of your console? Copying it as text does not always convey context very well

Comment: @Phil I have attached the screenshot of my console

Comment: @Thilina Sameera A problem here is, we can't sure what's the response type of your Ajax call, copy the console.log result as text not able to indicate that. Generally, when server response the content with header `Content-Type: application/json`, Javascript will consider the response as Object, which will able to access directly. Buy if server response the `Content-Type` in something else, you might need to do the `JSON.parse` yourself in your code

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are meeting seems to me that your response is a string. You need to decode it in order to get an object with [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

```js
const response = '{"download": "0.15698, 0.11142, 0.24579, 0.42217, 0.16009, 0.14763, 0.14108, 0.37508, 0.13011, 0.26782, 0.14398, 0.14989, 0.56165, 0.94662, 0.78994, 1.11108, 1.68576, 2.26573, 2.10515, 2.36522, 1.54842, 1.40649, 1.09299, 1.52076, 0.79385, 1.20544, 1.45247, ","upload": "0.19302, 0.18774, 0.18749, 0.22306, 0.30178, 0.32726, 0.25402, 0.24653, 0.23101, 0.47355, 0.16979, 0.19405, 0.22266, 0.26537, 0.25092, 0.26198, 0.18231, 0.21553, 0.22306, 0.21779, 0.20615, 0.20732, 0.18985, 0.17835, 0.16846, 0.19416, 0.15295, 0.14216, 0.17618, 0.24072, 0.15099, 0.18762, 0.16171, 0.19065, 0.18126, 0.19872, 0.19990, 0.16208, 0.17508, 0.22508, 0.20447, 0.21504, 1.22086, 1.38581, 1.29675, 1.19692, 1.30740, 1.04923, 1.19475, 1.30771, 1.22749, 1.17226, 1.34684, 1.15108, "}',
  obj = JSON.parse(response);

console.log(obj.download);
console.log(obj.upload);
```